# How to provide basis and the dimension of W? Give geometric interpretation of W.

Tags: linear-algebra

$W = { (x_1, x_2, x_3)^T: x_1\cdot  x_2\cdot x_3=0 }. $Is W a subspace? If yes, provide a basis and the dimension of W? Give geometric interpretation of W.

Comment: Are you sure $W$ is a subspace?

Answer (score 0):

Take $\;u=(1,1,0)^t\;,\;\;v:=(0,0,1)^t\;$ . Observe that $\;u\,,\,v\in W\;$ , but what can you say about $\;u+v\;$ ?

Comment: why I choose 1,1,0 and 0,0,1

Comment: @AkaliGreen Because you can. You know subspaces **must** be closed with respect to vector addition and scalar multiplication, right?

Answer (score 0):

In order for a vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to belong in $W$ at least one of its coordinates must be zero. Thus, a visual picture of $W$ consists of the three coordinate planes.

Now, it is clear that this is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$: a subspace must be closed under addition, but if you add two vectors belonging in two different coordinate planes, their sum does not belong in either of the three coordinate planes. For example: $(1,1,0)+(0,0,1)=(1,1,1)\notin W$.

Comment: Can you explain me why you use 110 and 001

Comment: I just picked two vectors in $W$, i.e. two vectors from two different coordinate planes to show that their some is not in $W$. There is no particular significance in the choice of the vectors. For example use $(0,1,1)$ and $(1,0,1)$ which are elements of $W$. However, their sum $(1,1,2)$ is obviously not in $W$.

Comment: how do I know that that isn't in W

Comment: @AkaliGreen Check it directly with the definition of $\;W\;$ !

Comment: $1\cdot 1\cdot 2=2$, so it does not satisfy the definition of $W$. $(1,1,2)$ does not belong to any of the coordinate planes.